# ASP.NET MVC change default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, maproute

I want my ASP.NET MVC application to redirect to Product controller index action by default. So I changed RouteConfig to

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        }
```

But still I am getting the error

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. 
The following locations were searched: 
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx 
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx 
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx 
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx 
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml 
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml 
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml 
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I debugged the application and checked the Defaults section of the third route. But it still says

`{[controller, Home]}`
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What does the `Index` method of `ProductController` return? (Looks like it is not specifying the view's name, and thus the default is being picked up.

Comment: @Richard Currently its just an empty method of return type ActionResult.

Comment: is your Index Method in ProductController or HomeController?

Comment: @Cris I have deleted the HomeController and the views related to it.

Comment: Not what is the return type, but what is returned by the method's `return` statement? If it is just `return View()` then you are telling MVC to use the view with the same name as the action.

Comment: @Richard Yes. It is just retun View(). But there is a view name index in the folder Views>Product.

Comment: OK, so the underlying issue two part 1. `ProductController` should be the default controller, but `HomeController` is; 2. There is no `HomeController` but there is no runtime error about not finding the `HomeController`? I would address the second part first because it *will* mess up any work on the first (start with a full rebuild of the solution).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me
Make sure the Default route is at the **BOTTOM** of your listed route table. Order matters when it comes to ASP.NET MVC Routing tables.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                  "Default",
                  "{id}",
                  new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
              );
```

also check [this tool](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) it'll helpful for you

Comment: Nope. Still the same problem.

Comment: try  cleaning then rebuilding your solution

Comment: Did that. Several times! Still no change. I just don't get it!

Comment: Close visual studio and reopen it worked for me (when rebuild doesn't...)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any views for Product Controller. Add views for it and it will work as expected.

Comment: I have added an index view for ProductController already. And anyway, as you can see form the error, it never looks for `~/Views/Product/Index.aspx`. That's what I wan't it to do!!

Comment: Delete the views related to home controller. And add view by right clicking on index method in product controller . Then check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will override the default route and use yours instead.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultApi", // Route name
            "{Controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }// Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```